# Volume of gas in containers

Tags: gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

If gases occupy all the volume in a container then how can we define 'volume percent' as all different gases will have same volume?

Comment: Most likely it's an open container with a piston i.e fixed pressure not volume

Comment: They had different volumes **before** we've mixed them.

Comment: @IvanNeretin it's not like that, as you can see that it's often stated  'oxygen is 21% by volume in air'.

Comment: @ShivamAgarwal say you have 2 mol of oxygen and 8 mol of nitrogen. Then the oxygen is 20% by volume (and 20% by mols if we assume they are all ideal gases)

Comment: @ShivamAgarwal This may be useful for answering your question if you are familiar with the concept of partial pressure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure#Partial_volume_(Amagat's_law_of_additive_volume)

Comment: I think this is a fair question. There isn't really much to add, although an example could help. In many high-school questions, the composition of the mixture if specified as x% gas X, y% gas Y, etc. Yet, when applying the ideal gas law, for each gas, the volume term $V$ is specified as the volume of the container, which implies they do occupy the whole volume.||Even if the answer to this question ends up being a single line, it does not - imho - does not justify closing the question. Thanks

Comment: I know it doesn't make much sense, but the term volume percent  typically has the meaning "mole percent."

Comment: Imagine nitrogen and oxygen in a cylinder separated by an infinitely thin barrier between the two gases. The height of the oxygen layer will be 21% of the total height and nitrogen 79%. Because we assume ideal gas behavior that means that if the barrier is removed, then after mixing a sample removed from the mixture will be 21% oxygen molecules and 79% nitrogen molecules.

Answer (score 1):

We can and do use volume fractions to express the level of a gas of vapour in air, it is volume ppm.  For example air to a first approximation is 20 % oxygen and 80 % nitrogen.

This means 20 % of the molecules in air are oxygen while 80 % are nitrogen. If we treat the gases as ideal gases then air is by volume 20 % oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

The point you have to remember about ideal gases (and gases at atmospheric pressure a a good approximation of ideal gases) is that the particles of the gas don't interact. This applies to *mixtures* as well as pure gases.

So, in one sense, if you fill a vessel with a mixture of gases, each *does* occupy the whole vessel. But the gases are also perfectly mixed as they don't separate out. If you calculated the pressure for a fixed amount of each gas *separately* in a vessel of a given size, then the answer you would get would be the *partial* pressure of the gas in a mixture containing the same amount of the specific gas.

As an alternative, if you kept the pressure fixed and calculated the volume occupied by the gas, the volume would be proportional to the amount of the gas. The volume of the components would add up the total volume of the vessel containing the mixture at the same pressure. This means that the volume % is proportional to the amount of gas molecules in the mixture and to the partial pressures. Volume and partial pressure are proportional for ideal gases so volume %, partial pressure and mole % are the same.